# Allocating large amount of memory to Kernel Module using vmalloc

Tags: c, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to allocate a large memory to kernel module using `vmalloc()`.
I am unable to allocate more than 2GB of memory on a 64-bit Linux (3.10.0-514.2.2.el7.x86_64) with 64GB ram.

These are the relevant code parts:

```
...

static int logical_block_size = 512;
module_param(logical_block_size, int, 0);
static int nsectors = 1024; /* How big the drive is */
module_param(nsectors, int, 0);

...

/*
 * The internal representation of our device.
*/
static struct sbd_device {
    unsigned long size;
    spinlock_t lock;
    u8 *data;
    struct gendisk *gd;
} Device;

...

static int __init sbd_init(void) {
    /*
     * Set up our internal device.
     */
   Device.size = nsectors * logical_block_size;
   spin_lock_init(&Device.lock);
   Device.data = vmalloc(Device.size);
   ...
```

Is there a limitation to the size of memory that can be allocated via `vmalloc`? Is there another way to allocate a large amount of memory to a kernel module?

Comment: In theory, the limit should be 32TB or the physically available ram, whatever comes first ;) Do you get some message from the kernel when trying to allocate it?

Comment: Show us how exactly are you using `vmalloc()`.

Comment: Allocating 2GiB RAM in a kernel module sounds like a very bad idea. Looks like an XY problem.

Comment: @Olaf Mind to elaborate why it is a bad idea? I tend to think, that it depends on the application and cannot find an argument, why there shouldn't be a valid reason for it.

Comment: @Ctx: Beacuse the amount of data has to be passed to the application some way. So why not allocate the memory dynamically in user space as required and pass to the kernel? One reason to use such large single  blocks is to handle everything in a big, bloat kernel module - typically a bad concept to mix different functions. Just to be clear: I did not say it always is a bad idea. But from the question being asked, I'm almost sure it is for whatever OP intends.

Comment: I am trying to write a block device driver that resides in memory for specific purpose. when trying to load the module i am getting - "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module xxx.ko: Cannot allocate memory"

Comment: code was taken from the following link: http://blog.superpat.com/2010/05/04/a-simple-block-driver-for-linux-kernel-2-6-31/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You refer to the code here: [Simple Block Driver](http://blog.superpat.com/2010/05/04/a-simple-block-driver-for-linux-kernel-2-6-31/) in the comments, which is essential to see to answer your question.

The reason is, that you are trying to allocate **16 Exabytes** of data.
This calculation in `sbd_init()` is the reason:

```
Device.size = nsectors * logical_block_size;
```

Device.size is `unsigned long` while the module parameters `nsectors` and `logical_block_size` are integers.

Now, when you set locgical_block_size to `1024` and nsectors to `2097152` (which totals to 2GB of space), the calculation is done as *signed integer*, thus the result is:

```
1024 * 2097152 = -2147483648
```

When this is casted implicitly to `unsigned long` (by the assignment to Device.size), the result is `18446744071562067968`, which is then passed to `vmalloc()`, (probably) slightly exceeding the physical memory and the vmalloc reserved area, which is 32TB on linux x86_64.

The solution is to perform the calculation as `unsigned long`:

```
Device.size = (unsigned long) nsectors * logical_block_size;
```

Then it should work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of Linux kernel there was a 64 MB limit on memory that `vmalloc()` can allocate but in version `3.10.*` it should theoretically be limited by the physical memory.

Comment: This should be a comment, since it doesn't really help to solve the OPs problem

Comment: @Ctx: This **answers** on *one of the asker's question* - `Is there a limitation to the size of memory that can be allocated via vmalloc?` So can be an *answer*.